# automatic layout of diagrams

Tags: layout, diagram, business-process-management

I need an algorithm for the automatic layout of BPMN2 diagrams.

Something like the auto layout (re-layout) of MS Visio.

Is there no similar OpenSource or comprehensive guidance?

[Sample Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/auto-align-auto-space-and-re-layout-shapes-in-a-diagram-a523b157-c8ff-47b0-9210-2f292de8ba20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [a very specific (and non-trivial) layout](https://www.yworks.com/pages/drawing-business-process-diagrams) you are looking for. There aren't many good implementation out there at all. A good -but commercial- implementation certainly is [yFiles - BPMN Demo](https://live.yworks.com/demos/complete/bpmn/index.html) - IMHO *easily* beats the layout of Visio from your sample link.

With regards to open source, you should be looking at a more generic layout style, probably, since BPMN really is a sophisticated corner-case of orthogonal flow layouts. Maybe [Kieler](http://www.rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/en/research/kieler), [GraphViz - dot](https://www.graphviz.org/) or [WebCola](http://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/) can be tweaked to work well enough for you for BPMN diagrams - but there is definitely a lot work left to do if you want to support all the sophisticated layout rules and options.